# How do I show multiple datapoints in HighMaps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show how a list of candidates fare in the 2012 US Elections.  Specifically, when the user hovers over a state I want to show a tooltip with multiple values on it.  Note that the shapes will all have the same color, regardless of method used (ie for multiple series each data-point for a shape will have the same color regardless of series).

I can think of a few ways to do this, but they aren't working out.

1. Use multiple data values in one series, with each data-point mapping to one shape (1:1).  However that doesn't seem possible, as the [series->data->value option](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#series.data.value) is a number.
2. Use multiple data points in one series, with each data-point mapping to one but possibly the same shape (N:1).  Here it seems that the latter data-points override the former.
3. Use multiple series (1 per party), with each data-point mapping to one shape (1:1 w/ multiple series).  Since both series map to all 50 states, the second series seems to overlay the first and is the only visible one until turned off via the legend.

Comment: Whoever voted to close as too broad... why?  Its a very specific problem.

Comment: Any chance you can update this with code?

Comment: Sure thing I'll try to add some in today. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the [tooltip->formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#tooltip.formatter) option to define custom HTML content.  I think another way would have been cleaner and am open to better answers!  But this works for now.